Prove that the group of unipotent matrices is nilpotent.
I'm trying to prove that the group of unipotent matrices (upper triangular with $1$'s on the diagonal) is nilpotent, so that the lower central series terminates in the trivial group after finite length.
For $n=2$, this post answers the question but I'm not sure on how to generalise this. Calculating the derived subgroup for $3\times3$ matrices already seems like a lot of calculation, so there has te be a quicker way somehow.

You can show it as in this post, or this post.

Serre gives a beautiful proof of this (IMO) in section 3.2 (example 3) of his Finite Groups book.
